# How to completely delete a CKAN user

Tags: ckan

I can delete a user with the web interface, but that only sets their state to deleted.  How do you completely remove a user?

Tried this, but didn't seem to work:

```
paster --plugin=ckan user remove bloggsj --config=/etc/ckan/std/std.ini
```

Also, when a user has been deleted (state set as deleted), how do you set them back to active?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently no paster or API call to purge a user.

At a pinch, you can do it from a paster shell though:

```
(ckan)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/src/ckan$ paster --plugin=pylons shell 
>>> model.User.get('testuser').purge()
>>> model.Session.commit()
>>> model.Session.remove()
```

People occasionally ask for purging for test purposes. The python test framework offers reset_db(), although if you wanted to do testing outside of python then it would potentially be useful.

If you feel it would be useful for this or another reason, I'd encourage you to submit a PR to CKAN.

BTW To undelete a user with state=deleted, a sysadmin can simply update the state field from 'deleted' to 'active' using the user_update API.

Comment: Thanks. For reference, changing the state back to active using httpie, syntax is:  
http http://your.ckan.instance.com/api/3/action/user_update id=username email=users@email.com state=active Authorization:sysadmin-api-key

Comment: My preference, avoiding the api key if you're ssh'd to the box, is to pip install ckanapi and then: ckanapi -c production.ini action user_update id=username stat=active

Comment: I ended up going with ```$ paster --plugin=pylons shell 
>>> user = model.User.get('testuser'); user.status='active';  model.Session.commit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming installed like [this](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html#setup-a-postgresql-database)

Connect to CKAN database:
`sudo -u postgres psql ckan_default`

To purge a single user:
`delete from only "user" where name ='user_to_delete';`

To re-activate a single user previously deleted:
`UPDATE "user" SET state='active' WHERE name='user_to_reactivate';`

---

To purge all inactive accounts (spammers / non-registered etc.):
`delete from only "user" where state!='active';`

Comment: That changes that users' 'sysadmin' property to 'false'. i.e. the user is not a sysadmin any more. It doesn't delete the user itself in any way.